# Pandas: Convert JSON to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Experts,

I am having issues parsing Json to Pandas and then save it in CSV format.

```
data2 = {"date":"2018-01-02","data":{"AAPL":{"open":"170.16","close":"172.26","high":"172.30","low":"169.26","volume":"25555934"},"MSFT":{"open":"86.13","close":"85.95","high":"86.31","low":"85.50","volume":"22483797"}}}
```

If I try :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(data2), orient='columns')
print(df)
```

Everything gets printed in a single line :

[image]

If I do :

```
jdata = json.loads(data2)
df = pd.DataFrame(jdata)
print(df.T)
```

I get an error : TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'

I am looking to print it in the following table format so I can then save it as csv :

```
Date        Data    Open    Close   High    Low     Volume
2018-01-02  AAPL    170.16  172.26  172.30  169.26  25555934
2018-01-02  MSFT    86.13   85.95   86.31   85.50   22483797
```

What is the correct way to achieve my goal ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `apply` to turn the dict keys into pandas `Series`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
df = pd.concat([df['date'],df['data'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
print(df)

            date    open   close    high     low    volume
AAPL  2018-01-02  170.16  172.26  172.30  169.26  25555934
MSFT  2018-01-02   86.13   85.95   86.31   85.50  22483797
```

Comment: This is very unefficient

Comment: @W-B, let me pick your brain, what is the difference vs the method you proposed ? What are the downsides ?

Comment: @EricArambula speed, apply is timing cost function , since you have stock data , when the size is increase , you will find apply + pd.Serise slow

Comment: from where does this data came from reference: df['data']  ?

Answer (score 1):

I will using your original output and modify it

```
s=pd.DataFrame(data2)
pd.concat([s.drop('data',1),pd.DataFrame(s.data.tolist(),index=s.index)],1)
            date   close    high     low    open    volume
AAPL  2018-01-02  172.26  172.30  169.26  170.16  25555934
MSFT  2018-01-02   85.95   86.31   85.50   86.13  22483797
```